# Combobox specific item c#

Tags: c#, combobox

I have many items in my combobox
one of them is a item called "Alert"
i want the code to know that when the selected item is "Alert" it launches an event
i work with c# and visual studio 2019 winform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=netcore-3.1)  event to the Combobox.
You can get the details like below.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    int selectedIndex = comboBox.SelectedIndex;
    int selectedValue = (int)comboBox.SelectedValue;
    string selectedItem = (string) comboBox.SelectedItem;
}
```